# <select> tag is not working on some android devices in ionic

Tags: html, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

So, select box is not working on android device(e.g. galaxy s6). I am using an ionic framework.. when i click on select box nothing appears, but if i click it at the border(it is very hard) options shows.  as i know it is a ionic's bug.. any solutions? thank you in advance [this is a select box image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhwxQ.png) [and this is options menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyEg2.jpg)

```
        <div class="list list-language">
            <label class="item item-input item-icon-left item-select">
                <div class="input-label">
                    <i class="flag {{ $root.locale }}"></i>
                    <i class="icon icon-arrow-right-alt"></i>
                </div>
                <select ng-model="$root.locale" ng-change="vm.changeLocale($root.locale)" tabindex="-1">
                    <option ng-selected="$root.locale == 'en'" value="en">{{ 'ENGLISH' | translate }}</option>
                    <option ng-selected="$root.locale == 'ka'" value="ka">{{ 'GEORGIAN' | translate }}</option>
                    <option ng-selected="$root.locale == 'ru'" value="ru">{{ 'RUSSIAN' | translate }}</option>
                </select>
            </label>
        </div>
```

Comment: have you try on another smartphone???

Comment: yes on some smartphones works, but on some no . for example : s6 or sony or ect.. also i tried other mobile apps written on ionic and also their selects don't work on my smartphone

Comment: which ionic version are u using 1 or 2 ???

Comment: i am using ionic v1

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Is there already a solution available?

Answer (score 6):

Try applying the `data-tap-disabled` attribute to the select tag. [Here's](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/page/tap/) some info on it. It basically disables the Ionic tap behavior that is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be related to your markup where you have label element wrapping div and select. Can you try to change label to smth else, for example to div. Or try to change div to span..

HTML does not allow a `<label>` to contain a `<div>`.

Comment: also tried this before writing question.. it is ionic bug but i interest if it is possible to fix this bug. i am using ionic 1